# Subtracting subset from larger dataset in R

Tags: r

Hi all:  I have two variables.  The first is entitled WITHOUT_VERANDAS. It is a list of cities, aggregated by average rental prices of homes WITHOUT verandas (there are about 200 rows):

```
City        Price

1 Appleton    5000
2 Ames        9000
3 Lodi        1020
4 Milwaukee   2010
5 Barstow     2000
6 Chicago     2320
7 Champaign   2000
```

The second variable is entitled WITH_VERANDAS.  It's a list of cities, aggregated by average rental prices of homes WITH verandas (there are about 10 rows, this is a subset of the previous dataset, since not every city has rental properties with verandas):

```
City          Price

1 Milwaukee   3000
2 Chicago     2050
3 Lodi        5000
```

For each city on the WITH_VERANDAS list, I want to subtract that city's WITHOUT_VERANDAS city value from the first list.  I want to see which cities have the highest or lowest differential.  Essentially, the result should only include the WITH_VERANDAS data.

I've tried this:

```
difference <- WITH_VERANDAS$Price-WITHOUT_VERANDAS$Price
View(difference)
```

However, this returns as many rows as the WITHOUT_VERANDAS dataset.  I also get an error:

```
   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

And the result is simply subtracting WITHOUT_VERANDAS's row 1 from WITH_VERANDA's row 1, as seen in the results:  (for example, row 1 of the output would be the value of Milwaukee-Appleton, row 2 output would be Chicago - Ames, and so forth)

```
 1.  -2000
 2.  -6950
```

If I could only filter WITHOUT_VERANDAS to include only the cities included in WITH_VERANDAS, I think it would work.  Thanks!

Comment: Try `merge(with_verandas, without_verandas, by="City", all=TRUE)`, and look at the resulting data.frame to see where to go next.

Answer (score 1):

R2evans, thank you !  this worked great.  Now, I have:

```
  City          Price.x       Price.y

  1  Appleton   NA            5000
  2  Ames       NA            9000
  3  Lodi       5000          1020
  4  Milwaukee  3000          2010
```

How would I go about filtering this list to take out any row where Price.x is "NA"?  i.e all rows that did not match. Thanks again!

Comment: What is your expected output? `full_join(df1, df2, by = "City") %>% filter(!is.na(Price.y))`

Comment: Akrun:  Desired output of the above table I included in my last response would be only the Lodi and Milwaukee rows.

Comment: so, I guess you can `filter` it based on the earlier comment

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you!